Is there a way to convert a List of type IFormFile to IFormFileCollection
In my code I have a OnPost() method that recieves an IFormCollection, through this I pass a few files through. One of these files I always want to always be the the index[0] of a List<byte[]>. Is there a way for me to convert this List<IFormFile> back to either the original IFormCollection or even to the IFormFileCollection?
Here is my code:
// Access form data
string? clientName = formData["client-name"]!;
string? comments = formData["comments"]!;
string? injury = formData["injury"]!;
var fileName = string.Empty;
List<byte[]> bytes = new List<byte[]>();
var blob = formData.Files["blob"];
// Access uploaded files
IFormFileCollection files = formData.Files;


if (blob != null && blob.Length > 0)
{
    using (var stream = blob.OpenReadStream())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        byte[] blobBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        bytes.Add(blobBytes);
        List<IFormFile> fileList = files.ToList();
        int indexRemover = fileList.FindIndex(file => file.FileName == "blob.png");

        if(indexRemover == -1)
        {
            fileList.RemoveAt(indexRemover);
        }


    }
}

Note: This isn't the whole method just the part where I am getting stuck. Go off the basis of the method looking like this:
public IActionResult OnPost(IFormCollection formData) {
 -- Previous code --
    return Page()
}

There is more to the method than this but for simplicity and straightforwardness I just included what I felt were the necessary pieces. If you need more information just let me know.

asp.net will do all the binding for you. (you're doing too much... you won't need to deal with IFormCollection at all) Just bind properties to your form field names. Use IFormFile or List type to bind to the file(s)... with name of <input type="file"... alternatively you can use Request.Form.Files which will be List

Building on the previous comment, I recommend spending a little time understanding how model binding works with public properties and parameters in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding, and then review uploading files: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload

The two of you are both correct. What I was doing was way to complicated for the task I needed to do. I'm pretty new to ASP.NET core and I mostly work with Blazor. Thanks for the links!
